# jQuery (or clean JS) - add callback to any function-parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

What I want looks like this:

```
function bindFunctions(bindFunction, callbackFunction) {
   // Add binding so that I can call the callbackFunction if the bindFunction is called
}

function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

function notifyUser() {
    alert('Something');
}

bindFunctions(log, notifyUser);


log('Error'); // Now the notifyUser-functions should be called and "Something" printed to the alert-box

bindFunctions($('.element').click, function() {/* CODE */}); // Or this: but I don't know if this is even possible because this is not the event-function but the binding-function of the click-event
```

**Important:** I have no influence on the `bindFunction` so it's not possible to implement a trigger there.

It's an attachment of a callback on any kind of existing function. Do you know how or if this is possible?

Comment: The way you've written it, no it's not possible. You can't change a function's behavior, and because JavaScript is pass-by-value you can't alter the original reference to the function with an API like you're suggesting. It *is* possible to wrap a function with another function that calls the first one after (or before) doing some additional work.

Comment: I also think it's not possible but maybe someone knows a dirty hack to implement this. But yeah I also thought about pass-by-reference which is not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking at it the wrong way.  What you need is some good old [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).  Whatever code needs `log` has to receive it from a higher-level component (e.g. the composition root of your application).  You're then free to implement a straightforward [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that calls `notifyUser` and [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) it instead of the actual `log`.

I've linked some articles taking an OO perspective, but feel free to translate to a more functional model (the approaches are equivalent).  In your case, you're using closures (which are, under a certain light, "equivalent" to objects with a single anonymous method).

Answer (score -1):

The way you have to do to add a callback to a function is this:

```
var foo = function(number, callback){
    number += 2;
    callback(number);
}

foo(2, function(result){
    window.alert(result)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6dpz88md/

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know what you mean but it's exactly not what I'm looking for. As I mentioned I dont know anything about the CALLED function. You wrote your own! I want to bind two abolute anonymous functions.